# Cannot access member object inside activity

Tags: java, android

Why can't I access remTime object? I get runtime exception while I can access all other Activity members declared the same way.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lstDayInterval, lstWeekDay, lstMonthDay, lstMonth;
        ...
    RemCalendar remTime;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...
        remTime.setToNow();

    }




public class RemCalendar  {

    private Calendar C;

    public RemCalendar() {
        C = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    public void setToNow() {
        C = Calendar.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you forget to initialize `remTime` instance  before calling method from `RemCalendar` class. initialize it inside `onCreate` :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ...
        remTime=new RemCalendar();
        remTime.setToNow();

    }
```

Comment: Coming from C++ I forgot have to new everything. But how is it I can use int member without new or initialize it right at member declaration?